# Is it possible to have an array of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have data that's coming from the server eg.

Name
Address
Telephone

Is there a way for me create an NSDictionary like:

```
(
  name=a_name,
  address=a_address,
  telephone=a_telephone
),
(
  name=b_name,
  address=b_address,
  telephone=b_telephone
)
```

Then after doing so, I will insert this dictionary into another dictionary.

So basically I would have a dictionary of something below;

```
(
  User=me,
  Details
  (
    name=a_name,
    address=a_address,
    telephone=a_telephone
  ),
  (
    name=b_name,
    address=b_address,
    telephone=b_telephone
  )
)
```

I am confuse on which to use between array and dictionary.

I have the ff: code:

```
[test addObject:dictionary];
```

test is an ns mutable array

which is an array, however, I do find it odd how to add it to a dictionary as there is no method to add a value of array and a key of just a string.

So the question might drag to something how to add an array object to NSDictionary.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is the basics of Foundation framework. You should dig more into documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

while (response) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:@"name_i" forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setObject:@"address_i" forKey:@"address"];
    [dict setObject:@"telephone_i" forKey:@"telephone"];
    [arr addObject:dict];
}
```

And also you can add Array into Dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *totalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[totalDict setObject:@"Me" forKey:@"User"];
[totalDict setObject:arr forKey:@"Details"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSArray *dictionary = @[
                              @{
                                @"Source_lat": @"28.6287",
                                @"Source_lon": @"77.3208",
                                @"Dest_lat": @"28.628454",
                                @"Dest_lon": @"77.376945",
                                @"S_address": @"Vaishali,Delhi",
                                },
                              @{
                                  @"Source_lat": @"28.628454",
                                  @"Source_lon": @"77.376945",
                                  @"Dest_lat": @"28.5529",
                                  @"Dest_lon": @"77.3367",
                                  @"S_address": @"Noida Sec 63",
                                  },
    @{
                                  @"Source_lat": @"28.5529",
                                  @"Source_lon": @"77.3367",
                                  @"Dest_lat": @"28.6276",
                                  @"Dest_lon": @"77.2784",
                                  @"S_address": @"Noida Sec 44",
                                  },
     @{
                                  @"Source_lat": @"28.6276",
                                  @"Source_lon": @"77.2784",
                                  @"Dest_lat": @"28.6287",
                                  @"Dest_lon": @"77.3208",
                                  @"S_address": @"Laxmi Nagar,Delhi",
                                  },



                             ];
```

May be Helpfull for You

Answer (score -1):

You should create a `NSMutableDictionary` and then use `setObject:ForKey` to add the `NSArray`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:test forKey:@"test"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a array of dictionary.

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

while (response) {
    [dict setObject:@"name_i" forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setObject:@"address_i" forKey:@"address"];
    [dict setObject:@"telephone_i" forKey:@"telephone"];
    [arr addObject:dict];
    [dict removeAllObjects];  
}
```

And also you can use dictionary of dictiory if you wish.

```
NSMutableDictionary *totalDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [totalDict setObject:dict forKey:@"i"];
```